# ¿Qué es "ser un cotilla"?

Tags: definiciones, palabras-raras, modismos

¿Qué significa esta palabra?

> Cotilla

¿y qué significa la siguiente frase?

> Ser un cotilla.

Tengo un significado, pero no sé si es el correcto.

> Cotilla: Que se entromete en asuntos ajenos.

Comment: Una persona cotilla es una persona que se entromete en asuntos ajenos como bien has dicho.

Comment: Interesante: [¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra cotilla?](http://www.muyhistoria.es/curiosidades/preguntas-respuestas/icual-es-el-origen-de-la-palabra-cotilla)

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, la palabra *cotilleo* se me hace más amigable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el DLE, [*cotilla*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B8woJee) significa:

> Persona amiga de chismes y cuentos.

Puede ser masculino o femenino, tiene caracter coloquial y también puede usarse como adjetivo. Tiene una evidente conexión etimológica con el verbo *cotillear*, que el diccionario señala como sinónimo de *chismorrear*. Este último, a su vez, [se define así](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8tjubls):

> Dicho de varias personas: Contarse chismes mutuamente.

Se trata de un verbo intransitivo (sin complemento directo: no se cotillea *algo* sino *acerca de algo*) y también de índole informal.

Comment: Entonces tiene un significado parecido al que tenía yo, se entromete en asuntos ajenos, **ser un cotilla** es **andar de chismoso**.

Answer (score 2):

"Cotilla" es un adjetivo cargado de cultura. Por ejemplo, en España, llamamos cotilla a aquella persona que siempre quiere saber de la vida de los demás (definición informal). Se trata de un peyorativo muy usado en España - el "cotilleo", el acto de "cotillear", se considera una *actividad* popular - fama sobre este rasgo de la cultura española se refleja en su folclore.

Ejemplos:

1. *¡Menudo cotilla estás hecho!*
2. *¡No seas cotilla!*
3. *No me gusta el cotilleo*
4. *No me fío de Carlos porque siempre está cotilleando*