# Origen de la palabra "cotilla"

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, historia, sustantivos

Una vez planteado el [origen de la palabra *chisme*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26336/12637), tras comentar que se puede equiparar a la palabra *[cotilleo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18017/12637)* me entró curiosidad también por ver de dónde viene esta. El resultado fue:

> **[cotilleo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B90oWzN)**
>
> 1. m. coloq. Acción y efecto de cotillear.

Así que nos vamos a verbo:

> **[cotillear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B8zW99j)**
>
> De *cotilla* y *-ear*.

Otro pasito más:

> **[cotilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B8woJee)**
>
> Del dim. de *cota*<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 1. f. Ajustador que usaban las mujeres, formado de lienzo o seda y de ballenas.
> 2. m. y f. coloq. Persona amiga de chismes y cuentos. U. t. c. adj.

Aquí ya advertimos que *cotilla* tiene una primera acepción que no tiene que ver con el significado figurado. De hecho, en el siguiente paso ya perdemos la pista:

> **[cota<sup>1</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B82EvYA)**
>
> Del fr. ant. *cote*, y este del franco **kotta* 'paño basto de lana';
>   *cf.* al. *Kotze, Kutte*.
>
> 1. f. Arma defensiva del cuerpo usada antiguamente, que en un principio era de cuero y guarnecida de cabezas de clavos o anillos de hierro, y más tarde, de mallas de hierro entrelazadas.
> 2. f. Vestidura que llevaban los reyes de armas en las funciones públicas, sobre la cual estaban bordados los escudos reales.
> 3. f. Cineg. Piel callosa que cubre la espaldilla y costillares del jabalí.
> 4. f. Mil. Fortaleza que hacían los indígenas filipinos con troncos de árboles revestidos de tierra y piedras menudas.
> 5. f. desus. jubón.

Así pues, la palabra debió de surgir a partir de la acepción de *cotilla* como prenda de vestir, pero en el *Diccionario de Autoridades* no vemos más acepción que esa:

> COTILLA. s.f. Jubón sin mangas hecho de dos telas, embutido con barba de ballena, y pespuntado, sobre el qual se visten las mugeres el jubón ò casaca, y trahen ajustado el cuerpo.

Así pues, ¿cuándo adquirió la palabra *cotilla* su acepción coloquial? ¿Cómo adquirió dicho significado?

Comment: @walen why not?

Comment: Corominas parece discrepar: distingue la etimologia de "**cotilla = corsé**", para la que remite a **cota** ('jubón, esp. el de cuero o de mallas llevado como arma defensiva'; del fr. ant. *cote* ....)  de la de "**cotilla = mujer chismosa**" para la que remite a **coto**, siendo coto: 'mandamiento, precepto', 'multa', 'término, límite, mojón', 'terreno acotado', 'tasa, límite fijado a los precios'

Answer (score 2):

En Chile (no sé si en otros países) a un kit de accesorios para fiestas le decimos **cotillón**, el que incluye habitualmente cornetas de cartón, papel picado, serpentinas y pelucas de colores.

La palabra *cotillón* parece tener una historia similar a la de *cotilla*, como se ve en la etimología del DRAE:

> **[cotillón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B94T37d)**
>
> Del fr. *cotillon*, aum. de *cotte* 'cota'.
>
> **1.** m. Fiesta y baile que se celebra en un día señalado como el de fin de año o Reyes.
>
> **2.** m. Danza con figuras, y generalmente en compás de vals, que solía ejecutarse al fin de los bailes de sociedad.
>
> **3.** m. Baile de sociedad en que al final se ejecutaba el cotillón.

En general en los diccionarios online de idioma francés el significado de *cotillon* coincide con el del español con respecto a lo de "fiesta" y "danza", pero también se indica el significado más antiguo de "falda" y "enagua", derivado de *cotte*, el cual a su vez significó "túnica" o "jubón".

Podemos suponer entonces que, en francés, de *cotte* ("túnica") se pasó a *cotillon* ("faldas") y de ahí por extensión al otro *cotillon* ("baile de las faldas", "fiesta", "objetos que se usan en las fiestas").

Y además, curiosamente, tanto en el diccionario de [leParisien](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/cotillon/fr-fr/) como en el [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cotillon), la palabra francesa *cotillon* significa "**mujer**", una metonimia similar a la que usamos al decir *enredos de faldas* (por decir "enredos de mujeres").

Más específicamente, Wiktionnaire da un ejemplo de 1855 y dice:

> 3. (Par extension) (Péjoratif) Femme, dans un jeu de séduction.
>
> [Traducción: (Por extensión) (Peyorativo) Mujer, en un juego de seducción.]

Yo imagino las fiestas francesas de otros tiempos, con todas esas mujeres al otro lado del salón, en campaña de seducción, y pienso que de ahí a lo de "mujeres chismosas" hay un paso.

Por lo tanto y en resumen, yo creo que *cotilla* con el significado de "chisme" viene del francés *cotte* ("jubón") siguiendo una historia similar a la de su similar francesa *cotillon*, en la que de "**pequeño jubón**" se pasó a "**falda**", de ahí a "**danza de faldas**", luego "**mujer en juego de seducción**" y finalmente "**mujer chismosa**".

---

(Nota aparte: curiosamente para la RAE *cotillon* sería un aumentativo de *cotte*, como se ve en la cita, cuando en realidad en francés el sufijo *-illon* corresponde a un diminutivo).

Comment: Rodrigo, creo que empezaste bien, pero el gran salto al final no me convenció.  Mira, creo que las mujeres jóvenes se fascinaban con el baile, pero las mujeres más maduras se interesaban más en las observaciones de la gente y las pláticas y chismeos.